# Parent class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

My `Game` class takes two arguments, but for some reason this code I wrote won't work:

```
class Game
{
    string consoleName;
    int gameID;

    public Game(string name, int id)
    {
        this.consoleName = name;
        this.gameID = id;
    }
}
```

Here is my child class.

```
class RolePlayingGame : Game
{
    int level;
}
```

Comment: Unlike (for instance) Delphi, C# doesn't automatically have sub classes inherit constructors with parameters. You need to explicitly define the same constructors in the sub classes.

Comment: When you don't specify any constructors, C# automatically creates something like a `public RolePlayingGame() : base() { }`. Since `Game` has no paramaterless constructor, this fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class RolePlayingGame : Game {
  public RolePlayingGame(string name, int id) : base(name, id){
    //...
  }
  int level;
}
```

Or provide a parameterless constructor for your base class:

```
class Game
{
   public Game(){ //You don't even need any code in this dummy constructor         
   }
   //....
}
```

**NOTE**: Note that if you understand a parameterless constructor is OK, you can use it (as provided in the second approach).

Comment: +1, but parameterless constructors for the sake of work-arounds would leave base-class members uninitialized. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice yes, agree. I'm going to add note about that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class RolePlayingGame : Game {
    public RolePlayingGame(string name, int id) : base(name, id){
        //Code here
    }
    int level;
}
```

As noted by Tim S in comments, C# automatically creates something like a `public RolePlayingGame() : base() { }`. Since `Game` does not have a parameterless constructor, this fails. So you need to create a parameterized constructor. You have to explicitly define the constructors in the sub classes.